# Regex pattern to get all lines text between two words

Tags: regex

I want to create a regex pattern to get stuff between two words.

```
Start:
Apple
Cat
Ball
End:
```

I want to get the data between Start: and End:

I was able to find this data using C#:

## region Get Required Field Data

```
    public static List<string> GetRequiredData(string[] lines, string StartPos, string EndPos)
    {
        List<String> RequiredField = new List<String>();


        bool hit = false;

        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            if (line == EndPos)
            {
                hit = false;
            }

            else if (hit == true)
            {
                if (line != "\t"||line=="")
                {
                    RequiredField.Add(line);
                   
                }
            }

            else if (line == StartPos)
            {
                hit = true;
            }


        }
        return RequiredField;
    }
    #endregion Get Required Field Data
```

But i think using regex for the same purpose will be cool.
I tried (?<=Start:)(.*)(?=End:) but it is not working.Plus i also want to remove any line in between with no text.

I will really appreciate any help.
Thank You,

Comment: You can indeed try RegExp: https://regex101.com/r/lC3oE8/1

Answer (score 6):

I'm not an expert in regex, but i gave it a try:

```
beginningword\n((.+\n)+)endingword
```

For a text:

```
beginningword
first line of whatever
second line of whatever
third line of whatever
endingword
```

Text that is matched to be group #1 is:

```
first line of whatever
second line of whatever
third line of whatever
```

Comment: I tried above pattern but it didn't worked.

Comment: (?s)(?<=beginningword).*?(?=endingword) worked for me.
But it doesn't remove extra spaces.
For an example:
beginningword


first line of whatever

second line of whatever

third line of whatever

endingword

It will also take the blank line.I was able to remove that line using methods String class in C#.Is it possible to remove these blank line using regex?

Comment: I think it's not possible with regex.

Comment: no problem i did remove the spaces using my code.But i still think it is possible using regex,Not sure how....I started learning it